# Warning /Fatal error require(MDB2.php) after install PHP PEAR and MDB2

Tags: php, pear

I have successfully installed PEAR and MDB2 on my **localhost**.
But when i am trying to run example code given by MDB2, i am getting error (In attached image)

Also Restarted Wamp server many times after installation.

**Error and Warning**

> Warning: `require(MDB2.php)`: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in `E:\wamp\www\pear_project\examples\example_php5.php` on line 8
>
> Fatal error: `require()`: Failed opening required 'MDB2.php' (`include_path='.;C:\php\pear'`) in `E:\wamp\www\pear_project\examples\example_php5.php` on line 8

**php.ini** is default modified by **go-pear** during **PEAR** installation.

```
;***** Added by go-pear
include_path=".;E:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12\pear"
;*****
```

[image]

```
<?php

/**************************************/
/* a nice php5 only show case of MDB2 */
/**************************************/

require 'MDB2.php';

// the database needs to be created manually beforehand
$dsn = array(
    'phptype'  => 'mysql',
    'username' => 'root',
#    'phptype'  => 'mysql',
#    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'hostspec' => 'localhost',
    'database' => 'driver_test',
);
#$dsn = 'sqlite:///:memory:';

// create MDB2 instance
$mdb2 = MDB2::factory($dsn);
if (MDB2::isError($mdb2)) {
    die($mdb2->getMessage());
}

// set the default fetchmode
$mdb2->setFetchMode(MDB2_FETCHMODE_ASSOC);

$fields = array(
    'id' => array(
        'type'     => 'integer',
        'unsigned' => true,
        'autoincrement'  => true,
    ),
    'somename' => array(
        'type'     => 'text',
        'length'   => 12,
    ),
    'somedate'  => array(
        'type'     => 'date',
    ),
);
$table = 'sometable';

// create a table
// since we are on php5 we can use the magic __call() method to:
// - load the manager module: $mdb2->loadModule('Manager', null, true);
// - redirect the method call to the manager module: $mdb2->manager->createTable('sometable', $fields);
$mdb2->mgCreateTable($table, $fields);

$query = "INSERT INTO $table (somename, somedate) VALUES (:name, :date)";
// parameters:
// 1) the query (notice we are using named parameters, but we could also use ? instead
// 2) types of the placeholders (either keyed numerically in order or by name)
// 3) MDB2_PREPARE_MANIP denotes a DML statement
$stmt = $mdb2->prepare($query, array('text', 'date'), MDB2_PREPARE_MANIP);
if (MDB2::isError($stmt)) {
    die($stmt->getMessage());
}

// load Date helper class
MDB2::loadFile('Date');

$stmt->execute(array('name' => 'hello', 'date' => MDB2_Date::mdbToday()));
// get the last inserted id
echo 'last insert id: ';
var_dump($mdb2->lastInsertId($table, 'id'));
$stmt->execute(array('name' => 'world', 'date' => '2005-11-11'));
// get the last inserted id
echo 'last insert id: ';
var_dump($mdb2->lastInsertId($table, 'id'));

// load Iterator implementations
MDB2::loadFile('Iterator');

$query = 'SELECT * FROM '.$table;
// parameters:
// 1) the query
// 2) true means MDB2 tries to determine the result set type automatically
// 3) true is the default and means that internally a MDB2_Result instance should be created
// 4) 'MDB2_BufferedIterator' means the MDB2_Result should be wrapped inside an SeekableIterator
$result = $mdb2->query($query, true, true, 'MDB2_BufferedIterator');

// iterate over the result set
foreach ($result as $row) {
    echo 'output row:<br>';
    var_dump($row);
}

// call drop table, since dropTable is not implemented in our instance
// but inside the loaded Manager module __call() will find it there and
// will redirect the call accordingly
// we could also have done:
//  $mdb2->manager->dropTable($table); or
//  $mdb2->mgDropTable($table);
$mdb2->dropTable($table);    
?>
```

Comment: Sorry, just deleted that needlessly. restart your webserver. Your file is looking in: .;C:\php\pear for your MDB2.php file, but it is located in .;E:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12\pear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem.
uninstall old WAMP and delete the rest wamp folder.
Then Fresh Install WAMP and PEAR.
Modify environment variable with the PHP folder path.

There is another php.ini in **E:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\bin**

Modify `php.ini` with the same include path

```
;***** Added by go-pear
include_path=".;E:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12\pear"
;*****
```

Install the Database Package MDB2,

and restart server.

Answer (score 0):

You should restart your web server whenever changes are made to php.ini, or they will not take effect.

Your current configuration is looking in: `include_path='.;C:\php\pear'`
however, your installation has this directory in: `E:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12\pear`

After restarting your wampp installation, it should begin working.

Comment: Are you sure you modified the proper php.ini file? Use phpinfo() to find out where the php.ini file location is, and check that php.ini file for the include path. It appears to be using: .;C:\php\pear as the default include path still. Why would this be looking in C:\php\pear when wamp is clearly installed on the E Drive anyways?